# узнать индекс ячейки на которую нажал пользователь (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Я разместил на ViewController TableView, а на ней TableViewCell. Хочу вызвать саму tableView, чтобы у нее вызвать indexPathForSelectedRow,  но он не находит tableView. Что сделать в данной ситуации?
"""

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
            guard let indexPath = 'tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow' else { return }
            let place = places[indexPath.row]
            let newPlaceVC = segue.destination as! NewPlaceTableViewController
            newPlaceVC.currentPlace = place
        }
    }
```

"""

Answer (score 0):

Нужно убрать кавычки вокруг tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow, иначе нет обращения к переменной indexPathForSelectedRow:

```
guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow else { return }
```

Comment: Кавычки я поставил для обозначения места, где это происходит, если убрать кавычки, то тоже не будет работать. Так как он просто не видит tableView

Comment: Посмотрите мой ответ на предыдущий ваш вопрос, там пример кода.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, удобнее будет сделать это через UITableViewDelegate

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var selectedPlace: String?
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
            let newPlaceVC = segue.destination as! NewPlaceTableViewController
            newPlaceVC.currentPlace = self.selectedPlace
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
        // Метод вызывается каждый раз при выделении ячейки
        self.selectedPlace = places[indexPath.row]
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetail", sender: self)
    }
}
```